# How many rectangles are there in the following figure?

Tags: mathematics, visual

I could count to 12 (update! actually it was 11). But the answer given is 14. For a vertical rectangle, there are 6 rectangles in it as drawn by me. Same is the case for horizontal rectangle except the middle common rectangle. So I did 
$6 * 2 - 1 = 12 - 1$ (common) $= 11$

> **Can you count 14 rectangles?**

[image]

Comment: I see 11 rectangles. Not sure where the other 3 will come from. The diagonals surely don't help.

Comment: Was 11 one of the lettered answers? The whole problem might have been sloppily translated from another language (and numbering system??), as seen in the grammar of "how many rectangle."

Comment: Do the three "dots" of the letters (a. b. c.) count to the figure? if so, they would be TINY rectangles (depending on the font.) Otherwise, I don't see 14 neither...

Comment: The lines themselves are "thick" as well. If you would allow them to be "rectangles" the count changes again... But +3 ?

Comment: The options are labelled 25, 14 and 13 and their values are given in hexadecimal. The answer is option 14: 0x0b = 11 rectangles. (No, that wasn't a serious comment either. `:)`)

Comment: @MOehm It actually *does* work for octal: $13_8 = 11_{10}$ :P

Comment: so i hereby conclude that there might be mistake in the book. Answer seems to be 11.

Answer (score 2):

Given the lines have non-zero thickness, I count 32.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:

> As pointed out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1980068)  to the related Math.SE question, the only way to count more than 11 rectangles in the image is to move the triangles around to make more rectangles.
>  If you use the four triangles to make two rectangles and then combine those rectangles, that gives you three more rectangles, making the total 14.  I can't really see how anyone would expect people to come up with this solution though...

Image (Excuse my bad artistic skills)

> [image]